# Parabola with offset in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot, graphs

The parabola seems to be plotted wrong, the vertex is located in (2,1), but tikz plot it around (-2,1).

- I have detected some issues while using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` that makes some graphs/nodes do not appear in the graph.
  But I don't know if this is messing around or simply the coordinates aren't right
  The slide is
  [image]
  and the parabole should be the next
  [image]

the code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{}
f $(2,2)$ d $y=8$
\end{block}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{6cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item$v(2,2)$
\item$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2}=\sqrt{(y-8)^2}$
\item$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=(y-8)^2$
\item$(x-2)^2+y^2-4y+4=y^2-16y+64$
\item$(x-2)^2-4y+4=-16y+64$
\item$(x-2)^2+12y=60$
\item$12y=60-(x-2)^2$
\item$y=5-\frac{(x-2)^2}{12}$

\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{6cm}
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.75}]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  %xtick={-10,-5,0,5,},
  %ytick={0,2,...,5,10,...,20},
  %xlabel={$\␣x$},
  %ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,grid]

\addplot[ blue, ultra thick,smooth,grid,domain=-10:10]
    {((60-((x+2)^2))/12))};
\addplot[ red, ultra thick,smooth,grid]
    {8};
\node[label={180:{(2,2)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:2,2) {};

\node[draw] at (7,8) {$y=8$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**NOTE**
the vertex was wrong at the first image of the slide, it was in `(2,2)` and it should be `(2,1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**

Your question is (unfortunately) not entirely clear, so I guess, that you actually have the following problems:

- how to define your function, that will has maximum at coordinates `(2,1)`:

  - this is a math problem, not `LaTeX` ...
  - anyway, by basic knowledge about quadratic functions is not hard to define it:

```
    (12-(x-2)^2)/12
```

- to show diagram symmetric to function maximum, you need to select its domain accordingly, for example: `domain=-6:10`

Off-topic: position of `column` contents is centered by default, so you not need to insert empty lines before image in the second column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} % recent is 1.17!

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{block}{}
f $(2,2)$ d $y=8$
    \end{block}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   $v(2,2)$
\item   $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2}=\sqrt{(y-8)^2}$
\item   $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=(y-8)^2$
\item   $(x-2)^2+y^2-4y+4=y^2-16y+64$
\item   $(x-2)^2-4y+4=-16y+64$
\item   $(x-2)^2+12y=60$
\item   $12y=60-(x-2)^2$
\item   $y=5-\frac{(x-2)^2}{12}$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
%
    \begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=black}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,
  axis lines=center,
  scale only axis,
  grid,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xtick={-8,-6,...,10},
  ytick={-6,-4,...,10},
  extra x ticks={0},
  tick label style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
  xlabel style={below}, ylabel style={left},
  xmin=-6.5,    xmax=11.5,
  ymin=-5.5,    ymax=9.5,
  domain=-6:10  % <---
            ]
\addplot [blue, very thick]    {(12-(x-2)^2)/12};
\draw[red,thick]    (-5,8) -- (7,8) node[right] {$y=8$};
\node[label={(2,2)},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (2,2) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```